# How can I pass app-specific configuration to Spark workers?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark app which uses many workers.  I'd like to be able to pass simple configuration information to them easily (without having to recompile): e.g. `USE_ALGO_A`.  If this was a local app, I'd just set the info in environment variables, and read them.  I've tried doing something similar using `spark-env.sh`, but the variables don't seem to propagate properly.

How can I do simple runtime configuration of my code in the workers?

(PS I'm running a `spark-ec2` type cluster)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of configuring each worker.

From the Spark docs:
You can edit `/root/spark/conf/spark-env.sh` on each machine to set Spark configuration options, such as JVM options. This file needs to be copied to every machine to reflect the change.

If you use an Amazon EC2 cluster, there is a script that RSYNC s a directory between teh master and all workers.

The easiest way to do this is to use a script we provide called copy-dir. First edit your `spark-env.sh` file on the master, then run `~/spark-ec2/copy-dir /root/spark/conf` to RSYNC it to all the workers.

see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html